# PHP dateRange function: how to save the return value in a var?

Tags: php, function

I have following php function, that creates an array of all the days between a start date and an end date:

```
function dateRange( $first, $last, $step = '+1 day', $format = 'Y-m-d' ) {

$dates = array();
$current = strtotime( $first );
$last = strtotime( $last );

while( $current <= $last ) {

    $dates[] = date( $format, $current );
    $current = strtotime( $step, $current );
    }

    return $dates;
}
```

I then use:

`if (in_array($this_date,dateRange($start_date, $end_date))) {... do sth ...} else {... do sth else...}`

Now I think to best implement this in a while-loop when reading the dates from the database. There are several date periods in the database and I would like to create an array with all of them when reading the rows, and finally check if in_array($this_array_contains_all_date_ranges_from_db).

If I try to print $array after using `dateRange($start_date,$end_date)`, it returns only an empty "Array". However, if I use the above mentioned if, it works fine. Also, I tried e.g. `$this_date_range=dateRange($start_date,$end_date);` but it was empty as well... I am not so experienced with functions, so I just could not figure out how can I create a var that will contain all the date ranges?

Thank you very much in advance!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say "print $array", are you doing a literal `print($array)`? Getting `Array` as the output from that is expected - you cannot `print()` an array. You have to use `print_r()` or `var_dump()`. Both will dump data structures into a textual format.

Comment: oh, you are a Genius, thank you Marc! :) I did not know that, thank you, this works now... :)

Comment: however, it works for returning one var, e.g. $total_dates=dateRange($start_date,$end_date), however, $total_dates.=... does not work!? It only takes the last value... How can I add multiple values to it then?

Comment: If you're returning an array, you'd have to use array notation, not string concatentation: `$total_dates[] = dateRange()`, or array_merge() and the like.

Comment: oh, wow... I would like to give you a double +, really! thank you so much, also for array_merge() as this would have been the next problem, you've solved it already before it occurred!! :) thank you Marc!